# insert statement with identity insert and sequence

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert some values into table but i am getting error. So basically i have a identity column auto insert on but for once i want to off it and insert the values and turn it back on again. So for that i have created a sequence and insert value by increment the id by 1

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ILevelDataItem] ON
GO

CREATE SEQUENCE iLevelDataitemSeq
START WITH 270
INCREMENT BY 1;

INSERT INTO tblA 
    SELECT 
        NEXT VALUE FOR iLevelDataitemSeq,
        REPLACE ([ReferenceDescription], 'LTM', 'RP'),
        [iLevelId]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[tblA] 
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ILevelDataItem] OFF
GO

DROP SEQUENCE iLevelDataitemSeq;
GO
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   An explicit value for the identity column in table 'dbo.tblA' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
>
> Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 39
>   Cannot drop the sequence 'iLevelDataitemSeq', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding all the column names like insert into tblA(c1,c2,c3) values ('','','')